# Split a list of numbers into lists of five with roughly the same sum

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of ~50 numbers (they’re all whole, but I don’t know if it matters) and I’d like to split it into lists of exactly five entries so that the sum of each group of five is the most similar to the others.

For example, if my list was like `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6}`, I’d like to get `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}}`.

Comment: Strongly suspect that in general, your problem is NP-complete (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness)

Comment: It is related to the Knapsack problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem.

Comment: In addition to what @yarchik commented, there must be something missing in the description. For instance, if I naively run `Total /@ DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[list, {5}]]` then every pair of the sums differs only by `1`.

Comment: @bmf It is asked to be "most similar", not "the same"

Comment: @yarchik yes I understood that. they are most similar. in the same way that 15 and 16 are most similar, 9 and 10 are also. the output of the command I wrote is this `{9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, \
15, 16, 15, 16, 17, 11, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 16, 13, 14, 15, 14, \
15, 16, 17, 16, 17, 18, 15, 16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 19, 20, 14, 15, 16, \
15, 16, 17, 18, 17, 18, 19, 16, 17, 18, 19, 18, 19, 20, 21, 19, 20, \
21, 22}`

Comment: You probably have to define a similarity measure to get an answer you want. As @yarchik stated, this is likely to be an NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

A non-rigorous approach.

Start with a sorted list

```
SeedRandom[1234];

list1 = RandomInteger[100, 52] // Sort

(* {2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 22, 26, 29, 32, 33, 36, \
38, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 47, 47, 47, 47, 51, 52, 53, 56, 59, 60, 60, 61, 66, \
66, 66, 68, 68, 72, 76, 86, 88, 88, 93, 97, 98} *)
```

Partition into five groups (discarding any extras)

```
list2 = Partition[list1, Floor[Length[list1]/5]] 

(* {{2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13}, {17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 22, 26, 29, 32, 
  33}, {36, 38, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 47, 47, 47}, {47, 51, 52, 53, 56, 59, 60, 
  60, 61, 66}, {66, 66, 68, 68, 72, 76, 86, 88, 88, 93}} *)
```

Reverse every other partition

```
list3 = Riffle[list2[[1 ;; ;; 2]], Reverse /@ list2[[2 ;; ;; 2]]]

(* {{2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13}, {33, 32, 29, 26, 22, 22, 21, 19, 18, 
  17}, {36, 38, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 47, 47, 47}, {66, 61, 60, 60, 59, 56, 53, 
  52, 51, 47}, {66, 66, 68, 68, 72, 76, 86, 88, 88, 93}} *)
```

Transpose into groups of five

```
list4 = Transpose[list3]

(* {{2, 33, 36, 66, 66}, {2, 32, 38, 61, 66}, {5, 29, 44, 60, 68}, {5, 26, 44, 
  60, 68}, {6, 22, 44, 59, 72}, {8, 22, 45, 56, 76}, {9, 21, 45, 53, 86}, {11,
   19, 47, 52, 88}, {12, 18, 47, 51, 88}, {13, 17, 47, 47, 93}} *)
```

The sums of each group are

```
sums = Total /@ list4

(* {203, 199, 206, 203, 203, 207, 214, 217, 216, 217} *)

MinMax@sums

(* {199, 217} *)
```

The variance of the sums are

```
var = Variance[sums] // N

(* 46.7222 *)
```

Comment: (+) A good starting point for iterative refinement.

Comment: I think this is good enough for what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I'll use the same example as from @BobHanlon. We can set this up as a 0-1 integer linear programming problem. We require a matrix of variables indexed by subset and list element. Each row will give a subset sum and each column will denote a list element position. If subsets have length 5 and the list has length 52 (as in this case), then there will be `Floor[52/5]=10` sublists. Constraints are that all variables are 0 or 1, row sums in this matrix are all 5 and column sums are all 1 or 0, that latter being the case for the leftover (unused) elements.

We take all differences of our subset sums, and minimize the maximum of these. Easy enough: just constrain a new variable to be greater-equal to all those differences, and minimize it.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
llen = 52;
list1 = RandomInteger[100, llen]
sublen = 5;
nsublists = Floor[llen/sublen];
vars = Array[x, {nsublists, llen}];
fvars = Flatten[vars];
subsums = vars . list1;
c1 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, fvars];
c2 = Map[Total[#] <= 1 &, Transpose@vars];
c3 = Map[Total[#] == sublen &, vars];
diffs = Flatten[Outer[Subtract, subsums, subsums]];
c4 = Map[min >= # &, diffs];
```

Now minimize, and reconstruct the subsets.

```
constraintsI = Join[c1, c2, c3, c4, {Element[fvars, Integers]}];
Timing[{diffmin, vals} = 
   FindMinimum[{min, constraintsI}, Join[{min}, fvars]];]
solmat = vars /. vals;
subsets = Table[Pick[list1, solmat[[j]], 1], {j, Length[solmat]}];
{diffmin, subsets}
(* Out[263]= {122.351, Null}

Out[266]= {0., {{5, 52, 36, 61, 68}, {44, 12, 13, 60, 93}, {47, 33, 
   29, 66, 47}, {45, 32, 6, 51, 88}, {26, 22, 86, 44, 44}, {5, 66, 18,
    88, 45}, {2, 72, 59, 21, 68}, {56, 2, 98, 47, 19}, {8, 17, 97, 53,
    47}, {9, 76, 11, 60, 66}}} *)
```

Interestingly, in this case the subset sums are all identical.

```
Map[Total, subsets]

(* Out[267]= {222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222} *)
```

An allusion to Baker Street? Lucifer over three? A schoolroom from [an early 70's TV show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_222)? I've no idea.